# How to get React state to only change one item being returned in a .map?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

It seems as though the way I'm writing my code below, when setLoading==true, it is changing all of my buttons to the loading state (true) when I only want the one being clicked to be changed. To further explain, I am simply displaying a spinner on the button when loading==true. Any idea as to how I can get this to behave properly? I figured it was a key issue, but that isn't the case, as I have a unique key for every element being returned.

Thank you all very much!

```
        //Function called to set the state 
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

        exampleArray.map((exampleObject, index) => {
          return(
            <div className={resulStyle.result} key={exampleObject.hash}>
                <button key={exampleObject} onClick = {() => {router.push(`/queryFamily/${exampleObject.hash}`); setLoading(true);}}>{loading ? 
                <div className="spinner-box">
                <div className="pulse-container small">  
                  <div className="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-1"></div>
                  <div className="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-2"></div>
                  <div className="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-3"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
                : "View Pricing"}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well yes, and you should expect that to be the case. Here you have one component and you are keeping a string value as the state. If you change this state to `true`, React will render all your buttons with the loading state.

The solution is to create a component for your button and keep the state there and use that component here.

Example for that button component would look like this:

```js
function MyButton() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  return loading ? <Spinner /> : <button onClick={() => {your_thing; setLoading(true);}}>Something!</button>
}
```

Comment: I figured that was the solution- thanks :) Been a while since I've used React

Comment: Most welcome! Please consider accepting my answer if you think it's a good resolution to your question

Comment: Sure! It won't let me for 7 minutes, but I will once the timer is up.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the id/unique identifier of the button that is clicked as currentButtonLoading (or whatever): when mapping, see if that unique identifier === currentButtonLoading, then use your loading state to only impact that singular button.

Answer (score 0):

Since loading is a variable set on state level it will be taken for all the buttons you render.
Why don't you use another state variable

const [currentButtonIndex, setCurrentButtonIndex] = useState();

And then on click set
setCurrentButtonIndex(index)

And in condition use
index===currentButtonIndex && loading